# SECONDARY clipboard

Tags: x11, clipboard

I know that `X` has three clipboards. How do I use the `SECONDARY` clipboard? Is there a shortcut for copying/pasting from it?

Comment: shortcuts are application-specific (though you may rely upon window-manager shortcuts).  You can only get useful answers by specifying the application that you want to configure.

Comment: There was no accepted answer for that, and the given answers wouldn't be that helpful in any case.